# Android SQLite: I can't select with integer field

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, cursor

I can't run this code in android using java and sqlite.

This code doesnt work:

```
Cursor c = read.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM frentista WHERE cast(codigo as text) = '4",null);
```

this code works:

```
Cursor c = read.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM frentista WHERE nome = 'DANIEL'",null);
```

I've tried with CAST and without CAST.

I've created my table with this code:

```
        sql = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frentista ( "+
            " codigo INTEGER,"+
            " nome TEXT,"+
            " rfid TEXT,"+
            " senha TEXT,"+
            " premia TEXT"+
            " )";
```

And this is my whole method

```
    public Frentista select(int codigo) {
    String[] rfid;
    List<FrentistaRfid> listFrentistaRfid = new ArrayList<>();
    Frentista frentista = new Frentista();
    try {
        Cursor c = read.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM frentista WHERE nome = 'DANIEL'",null);

        Log.i("QTD_FRENT", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Log.i("SELECT_VEND", "ENTROU NO WHILE");
            frentista.setCodigo(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("codigo")));
            frentista.setNome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            Log.i("FRENTISTA_SELECT", frentista.getNome());
            frentista.setSenha(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("senha")));
            frentista.setPremia(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("premia")));
            rfid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rfid")).split(",");
            for(String item : rfid) {
                listFrentistaRfid.add(new FrentistaRfid(item));
            }
            frentista.setRfid(listFrentistaRfid);

            c.moveToNext();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("ERRO SELECT FRENTISTA: ",e.getMessage());
    }
    return frentista;
}
```

When i try SELECT without WHERE clause, it's work. My problem is with WHERE with INTEGER FIELD.

Cursor stay empty when my where is with INTEGER field

Comment: Your code does not work because you missed the closing single quote for `4`. Voting to close the question because the problem is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Cursor c = read.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM frentista WHERE codigo = " + 4 ,null);
```

Comment: I discovered the problem, I was using the spinner ID, not the record id, so I couldn't find the record in the database. Thank you